# The region under a non-negative measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a non-negative measurable function on $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ and let
$$R(f)=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{d+1}:x\in E,0\leq y\leq f(x)\}.$$
Then it's a well-known result in Real Analysis that $R(f)$ is measurable. If we define
$$\bar{f}(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x)&x\in E\\
0&x\notin E,
\end{cases}$$
and $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, then is it possible to prove that $m(R(f))=m(R(\bar{f}))$? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By Fubini\Tonelli's Theorem $m(R(f))=\int_E \int_0^{f(x)} dydx=\int_E f(x)dx$. Since $\int_{\mathbb R^{d}} \overline {f} (x)dx=\int_E f(x)dx$ we get $m(R(f))=m(R(\overline {f}))$.

Comment: In my book(Stein&Shakarchi), $\int_E f$ is defined to be $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\bar{f}$.

Comment: @Steve I have edited the answer to make it compatible with your notations.

Comment: Sir, I have a hard time understanding the meaning of $\int_E \int_0^{f(x)} dydx$. After all, the authors of my text define the integral of a function on the whole space, not a function on a subset of the space, as in my first comment.

Comment: It seems like the Fubini theorem you are talking about embodies the definition of the integral of a function defined on a subset of the space.